# Why does calling write on an unrelated integer variable deallocate an unlimited polymorphic pointer in Fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, polymorphism, gfortran

I am attempting to save any kind of value in a unlimited polymorphic class pointer then retrieve the value using functions that will return a value as a specific type. I've written the code just for integers so far.

filename: pointers.f90

```fortran
module pointers_example
contains
  subroutine assign_int(pt,val)
    class(*),allocatable,target :: temp
    class(*),pointer,intent(inout) :: pt
    integer,intent(in) :: val

    allocate(temp,source=val)
    pt => temp

  end subroutine assign_int

  pure function int_val(pt) result (val)
    class(*),intent(in) :: pt
    integer :: val

    select type(v => pt)
    type is (integer)
       val = v
    end select
    return
  end function int_val

end module pointers_example

program main
  use pointers_example
  implicit none
  class(*),pointer :: pt
  integer :: i = 10
  integer :: output_unit = 6


  call assign_int(pt,10)
  write(output_unit,'("1. int_val(pt) = ",I2)') int_val(pt)
  write(output_unit,'("i == int_val(pt)? ",L1)') int_val(pt) == i
  write(output_unit,'("i = ",I2)') i
  write(output_unit,'("2. int_val(pt) = ",I2)') int_val(pt)
  write(output_unit,'("i == int_val(pt)? ",L1)') int_val(pt) == i
  call assign_int(pt,10)
  write(output_unit,'("3. int_val(pt) = ",I2)') int_val(pt)

end program main
```

When I compile it with gfortran and run the code I get:

```
$ gfortran -o pointers pointers.f90 ; ./pointers
1. int_val(pt) = 10
i == int_val(pt)? T
i = 10
2. int_val(pt) = **
i == int_val(pt)? F
3. int_val(pt) =  0
```

I wouldn't expect the int_val(pt) == ** in the second case. The comparison int_val(i) == i seems to suggest that they are both integers with the same value before the call to **write(output_unit,'("i = ",I2)') i** but that they are not the same afterwards. It also seems like there is an additional side effect of write outside of printing to console that I'm not aware of. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Your program runs correctly when built with Intel Fortran 19.0.5. It may just be a bug in your version of gfortran - a WRITE should not change other values. Sometimes this sort of behavior is caused by coding errors, but I haven't spotted one here yet.

Comment: Thank you for checking this with ifort. I am extremely hesitant to say there is an error in a compiler, but it may be the case here. (edit: just fyi, I am using the latest GNU Fortran 9.2.0)

Comment: The variable `temp` is a local allocatable variable in `assign_ptr`. Fortran standard states:  _When the execution of a procedure is terminated by execution of a RETURN or END statement, an unsaved allocatable local variable of the procedure retains its allocation and definition status if it is a function result or a subobject thereof; otherwise, if it is allocated it will be deallocated._  `temp is deallocated.  You then need to look at 19.5.2.5: _The association status of a pointer becomes undefined when ...  (3) the target of the pointer is deallocated other than through the pointer,_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @evets response, I figured out the solution. I've left the old code commented out:

```
subroutine assign_int(pt,val)
    !class(*),allocatable,target :: temp
    class(*),pointer,intent(inout) :: pt
    integer,target,intent(in) :: val

    ! allocate(pt,source=val)
    ! pt => temp
    pt => val
end subroutine assign_int
```

Essentially, the temporary (temp) pointer was being deallocated because it was unsaved and not returned by the **assign_int** function. According to the Fortran standard "19.5.2.5: The association status of a pointer becomes undefined when ... (3) the target of the pointer is deallocated other than through the pointer", the pt target was undefined.